# PHP Syntax Error for simple web script

Tags: php

Running into an issue with a simple PHP script and I can't seem to figure it out. States its on line 3 and I don't see it. Need a fresh set of eyes please.

```
   <?php

     $numArr = [];
         for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
          array_push($numArr,mt_rand());
        }
     echo min($numArr);

    ?>
```

Comment: No syntax error when I run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely how you're initializing your array. The `[]` syntax is only available from PHP 5.4 and above.

[From the PHP manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func)

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

You can use `array ()` instead.